# HTTP Status for "already logged in"

Tags: http, rest, authentication

Say a REST client is logged in and attempts to login again, in which case the server ignores the request. What status should be returned here?

Comment: How does this login happen? HTTP Basic Auth? How is the login state related to REST?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think your API could get away with returning the exact same status code / message as it would if it were a successful *first* login.

Here's why...
The way I see it, you have two different scenarios from the perspective of the API: new login and re-login. programmatically there is a difference.

But, from the perspective of the API consumer, all the consumer wants to know is if login was successful, which it was.

Comment: I agree, wholeheartedly.

Comment: So it's basically idempotent. Makes sense.

Comment: login is a POST, which should not be idempotent

Comment: What if another user is logged in?